# Getting Error setting Title for the UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, uibutton

Im attempting to make the title of a `UIButton` the favorites count of the particular `tweet` from twitter. I can functionally attain the number and I am successfully authorized with Twitter. Here is how I am attempting to set the Title:

```
        //Set number of Favorites for Tweet
        NSObject *favoritesCount = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"favourites_count"];
        UIButton *favoritesButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:204];
        favoritesButton.titleLabel.text = favoritesCount;
```

When I run this I get the error at `favoritesButton.titleLabel.text = favoritesCount;`

Here is the error I am getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d3a3a0'
```

Comment: What happens if you change the NSObject * favouritesCount to just NSObject * favourites ?

Comment: Why you are using NSObject to get count only?

Comment: ok that means that `[cell viewWithTag:204];` delivers wrong object. how do you add that uibutton to the cellview? is it still valid? dont you want to use properties instead of view tagging?

Comment: Have you tried:  `[favoritesButton setTitle:tile forState:UIControlStateNormal]`, as Bhumeshwer katre says change nsobject to NSInteger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title should be NSString value. You need to set title as NSString not NSObject.

```
    NSInteger favoritesCount = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"favourites_count"];
    UIButton *favoritesButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:204];
    favoritesButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",favoritesCount];
```